# NSArrayController and specific entities

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsarraycontroller

Maybe I don't understand how to use a `NSArrayController` correctly, but here's my situation.

I have my entities set up like this: `Account -> Folder -> Chat`. So I'll have lots of chats for a specific folder entity. I'm wanting my array controller to only be bound to chat entities from a specific folder entity. What's a way I can go about this? I have a reference to the folder entity that I want the chats from.

Comment: What do you mean by entity -- are you using core data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a fetch request using your folder entity as the argument.  When you execute the request with executeFetchRequest:error:, the return value will be an array that can be bound to your array controller.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I totally didn't make that clear. These are entities I'm talking about, not a directory. I'll update the question. Thanks for your answer though, appreciate the time.

Comment: @Yep, sorry I misunderstood your question.  See my edited answer.

Comment: This is on OS X, as indicated by my tags. OS X doesn't have `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: I didn't say to use an NSFetchedResultsController.  You create the fetch request with an NSFetchRequest class method, and execute it with the method I mentioned, which is  method of NSManagedObjectContext, both of which are available in OS X.

Comment: :/ I'm so tired tonight. Thanks!